# ORACLE select lacks row

Tags: database, oracle

I use ORACLE setup RAC cluster.

My problem is when DB got problem (still dont know the reason ) my sql select lacks rows

example:

```
select * 
from student_detail 
where student_id = 1231
```

should return 10 row data of student have id 1231, but in this case just return 6 rows

can anybody help me to understand this problem!

Comment: You seem to be defining that the database has a problem based on whether all the rows you expect are being returned. If there's some other symptom then you should certainly tell us what it is.

Comment: Is `student_detail` a view? Do you have VPD enabled?

Comment: query is ok. There is other data stored in student_detail that you expect to receive.  Maybe you connect to wrong db instance?

Comment: This question will be closed because it is impossible for us to remotely diagnose the problem on the basis of the information provided.  Alas we are not telepathic.  We only know what you tell us.  At the *very least* you need to provide a working test case: some sample data and some the desired and actual outputs.

Answer (score 2):

As a general observation, an Oracle SELECT always returns the *correct* number of rows.  If the result set does not match your expectation then there is a problem with your understanding.

For instance you may have miscounted the number of rows with `student_id = 1231`.  If the query returns only six rows how do you know there are supposed to be ten?  It might not be as simple as eyeballing ...

```
select * from student_detail
order by student_id
```

... if `student_id` has a varchar2 datatype and some IDs are suffixed with stray spaces.  A query like this will diagnose that problem:

```
select student_id, count(*)
from student_detail
group by student_id
order by student_id
```

Other possible causes?  A misleading view?  Row Level Security restricting the result set?  Some bizarre client-side configuration which only shows the first six rows instead of the entire set?

You mention RAC.  RAC uses a mechanism called the [Global Cache Service Process](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/rac.102/b14197/admcon.htm#sthref75) to transmit changed data to different nodes.  It is possible you are experiencing a failure in this process.  Talk to your DBA and get them to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the data should be wrong.
for example, if the data of user_id is '1231', that's not wrong, but if the data is left gap
 like ' 1231', you can't see the data.

' 1231 ' , '1231 ' also can not be printed out. 
The solution is when you insert some data, use the function 'trim' or 'replace'...
trim is only remove left gap.